# Can I place an induction cooktop on a 3/4-inch wood cutting board on top of a metal gas stove?

Tags: induction, safety

The cutting board is large and covers the top of the stove but not the side and back metal strips. Will this interfere with the use of the cooktop? Is it dangerous? Should I just remove all metal from around the induction cooker?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  In order to answer your question, it would be helpful to have more detail on what information you're specifically seeking.  What dangers are you concerned about?

Comment: I don't believe they typically give a fig for what's under or around them, just what's on top. Can set them on a metal countertop... Got a specific model number / brand in mind? Look up the manual.

Comment: I don’t think materials matter as much as stability and maybe height.  I’d be most concerned with something like a large pot of liquids that might tip over.

Comment: I think magnetic lines of force extend equally above and below the element that creates them, so you're right to be concerned.  I'd worry about the stove grates heating up.

Comment: Mark: no, really, they don't.  The inverse square law protects you from that.

Answer (score 5):

I put my portable induction single burner stove unit on top of a breadboard on my stove w/ no problems. However, I have now switched to a large stainless steel cookie sheet (in case someone accidentally lit the burner on the stove.)

Comment: I assume the cookie sheet doesn't get warm from using the induction hotplate. This would be nice experimental confirmation of Fuzzy Chef's point in the comments, to satisfy anyone not convinced by theory.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a good idea to put child safety locks on the knobs to prevent anyone accidentally turning the gas stove on.

Comment: Welcome Susan! That's a good point. It seems you construed the question as about general dangers; admittedly the concern with the stove's metal was not strongly enunciated. Yet such incidental points fit better in a comment next time. Relish it!